# Is it possible to write a simple code that will mass rename files inside of a folder, by removing the name of the folder?

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, rename

So I've got a lot of files (roughly 1,400) that are spread out through roughly 500 folders. All of these files have the name of the folder they're in as part of their name. I need to rename them and remove the folder name from them.

I've tried using Batch Rename Utility but it requires a commercial license to run its javascript program. I've tried working with DOS code, but my last time using DOS or scripting was back in my college days (a decade or more past).

I'm afraid I don't know the code. As long as it works simply, I'd be happy. I'm just tryin' to save my brain from snapping by automating it.

For example, I have a folder named GREEN, and within that folder is a file named YELLOW-sun and YELLOW plant and Yellow car or anything else with "Green" in its name.

I want to have the files automatically renamed (either run once per folder, or a full run of all the subfolders in the main folder) so that it becomes -Mulch or Grass or car or anything else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I added a comment below to help futher explain this, as I wasn't clear.*

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/) Anyway, what have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Also take the [tour] and [ask] here! Your question as it stands is just a code request which is too broad and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: The description indicate that "these files have the name of the folder they're in as part of their name" so, for example, if you have a folder named GREEN, then there should be files with "GREEN" in its name. However, your example with the "YELLOW" files contradicts the description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea might sound feasible, but a quick check with a small PowerShell script quickly reveals hidden pitfalls.
As soon as numbers/dates are involved you will rename files you don't want to.

```
ForEach($Dir in Get-ChildItem -Path Q:\Test\2019 -Directory -Recurse){
 Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir.FullName -File -Filter "*$($Dir.Name)*" |
   Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Dir.Name} -WhatIf
}
```

(To be on topic, that could be wrapped in a batch)

Sample run on my Test folder from this year:

```
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\01\01\SO_53992011.ps1 Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\01\01\SO_539921.ps1".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\01\01\SO_54013736.txt Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\01\01\SO_543736.txt".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\01\04\SO_54044173.ps1 Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\01\04\SO_544173.ps1".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\01\06\SO_54064719.cmd Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\01\06\SO_544719.cmd".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\01\07\SO_54070456.cmd Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\01\07\SO_540456.cmd".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\01\07\SO_54075981.ps1 Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\01\07\SO_545981.ps1".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\01\14\SO_54181420.ps1 Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\01\14\SO_541820.ps1".
%<---------------->%
```

Batch/cmdline variant with aliases and `-WhatIf` to see what would be executed

```
powershell -NoP -C "ForEach($Dir in gci . -Dir -Rec){gci $Dir.FullName -File -Filter \"*$($Dir.Name)*\"|Ren -NewN {$_.Name -replace $Dir.Name} -WhatIf }"
```

Same without seatbelts:

```
powershell -NoP -C "ForEach($Dir in gci . -Dir -Rec){gci $Dir.FullName -File -Filter \"*$($Dir.Name)*\"|Ren -NewN {$_.Name -replace $Dir.Name} }"
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too clear apparently.

I have a lot of files with a variety of names. However, there are some common threads to them, & I was able to sort them into folders named upon those threads.

Now however, I need to do another adjustment to those files, & simplify the names down. For example, I've got a lot of files with the word "Green" or "Yellow" or "Blue" in them. I've used the common words in them to name folders & sort them into them, but now I need to go back & remove folder name from file name. My question is how? My only past experience is DOS/C#, years ago.

Comment: You were clear enough, my script as is will do what you want, I'll wrap it i in a batch/cmd line to run from current folder. If the output from 1st variant looks OK, use the 2nd one.

Comment: You are a saint and a scholar LotPings! Thank you greatly. You've just saved my poor old brain. Thank you.

Comment: Hint for a new contributor: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (once you've got a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of 15 it will be seen)